# how do you make sql null value into a number?

Tags: sql, laravel

i have joined table then made it into array like this

[image]

so on array number 1 and 2, there's no item in the database that's why  the `qty_stock` returned null

is there a way to turn the null on `qty_stock` into a number `0`?

here's my code

```
$getmaterial = ContractProduct::select(
        'contract_product.ref_contract_id',
        'contract_product.ref_product_id',
        'product_item.name as product_name',
        'contract_product.qty as qty_taken',
        'stock.qty_stock',
        'contract_product.unit_price as price',
        'contract_product.sub_total_price as budget',
        \DB::raw('ABS(stock.qty_stock - contract_product.qty) as qty')
      )
      ->leftjoin('contract_document', 'contract_product.ref_contract_id', '=', 'contract_document.contract_id')
      ->leftjoin('product_item', 'contract_product.ref_product_id', '=', 'product_item.code')
      ->leftjoin('stock', 'contract_product.ref_product_id', '=', 'stock.ref_product_id')
      ->where('contract_document.ref_project_id', $getquoid->project_id)
      ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COALESCE()`:

```
coalesce(stock.qty_stock, 0) as qty_stock
```

`COALESCE()` is the standard SQL function to replace `NULL` values.  It returns the first value that is not `NULL` its arguments -- there can be any number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing this on the `$getmaterial` variable instead of doing this with the Query Builder (i.e. using `COALESCE`):

Wherever you use `qty_stock`, you can simply say:

```
print($getmaterial[0].qty_stock | 0);
```

This is my favorite solution for these kinds of cases. This will **not replace** all `NULL` values of `qty_stock` in the array, but it will use `0` when you place `| 0` after every `NULL` value (also works for `false`, `undefined`, `0` etc. Basically all possible `false` values).

If you really want to **replace** all `NULL` values inside your `$getmaterial` Array, I recommend using a for-loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $getmaterial->count(); $i++) {
    $getmaterial[i].qty_stock = $getmaterial[i].qty_stock | 0;
}

// or:

for ($i = 0; $i < $getmaterial->count(); $i++) {
    if ($getmaterial[i].qty_stock == null) {
        $getmaterial[i].qty_stock = 0;
    }
}
```

Whichever you prefer. However, the latter is not very efficient when your array contains a lot of items. But if this is indeed the case, you should actually paginate your query: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to replace `NULL` with 0 then you can use `COALESCE` or `CASE WHEN`

```
CASE WHEN stock.qty_stock is not null then stock.qty_stock else 0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()` for this purpose both works same way.

```
IFNULL(stock.qty_stock, 0) as qty_stock
```

OR

```
COALESCE(stock.qty_stock, 0) as qty_stock
```

This both return 0 for null qty_stock.

And if you want 1 for null qty_stock you have one more option along with this two.

```
ISNULL(stock.qty_stock) as qty_stock
```

This will return 1 for null qty_stock.